# Detecting concurrent logins in Angular JS + Spring boot web app

Tags: spring-boot, spring-session

I want to be able to detect concurrent logins and let the user decide what action to choose. When a concurrent login is detected I would like to let the new user choose from the following:

- login and logout the old user
- cancel new user login so the old user is still signed in.

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: how do i achieve the behavior described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control this if you are using `spring-security`. The following code sample is for a spring-boot web app using `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-security` dependencies (and a spring-session flavour as well if required)
Assuming you do not want more than 2 concurrent logins from the same user, and you want to prevent any future logins:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

   //override this method as required
   public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {} 


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement()
             .maximumSessions(2)
             .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)//prevents login for > 2attempts and sends to the authentication-failure-url
             .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        return new SessionRegistryImpl();
    }
}
```

If you want fine-grained control, you can take the `sessionRegistry` bean above and use it to get principals (users) and expire their sessions etc.

More information can be found in the documentation at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions